# Yii 2 redirecting to Login if Guest visit the website

Tags: redirect, authentication, yii2

I need some advice how to make  redirecting to login if someone does not login into the website and he is only Guest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Yii;
use \yii\helpers\Url;

if ( Yii::$app->user->isGuest )
    return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(array(Url::to(['site/login'],302)));
```

Use can use it in actions or views , but if you need to use it in lots of actions you probably need look at [AccessControl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html) and restrict access even before action is fired

Comment: I should put it in every controller or ...?

Comment: @MaksymSemenykhin
Can i use in this way `return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(SITE_URL.'login');` ?
Why are you writed getResponse function ? what is use of it?

I have written this way but I am not getting referrer on login page.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options:

1. You can use the AccessControl as mentioned by @Maksym Semenykhin
2. You can use the option below especially when you would like the logged user to be returned to this page after login.

   ```
   public function beforeAction($action){
   if (parent::beforeAction($action)){
       if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
           Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = ['/auth/default/index', 'return' => \Yii::$app->request->url];
           return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->loginUrl)->send();
       }
   }}
   ```

   You can also create a custom 'Controller' class which inherits \yii\web\Controller then have all controllers that need authorization inherit your custom controller.

On the login function, replace the redirect part with the following code:

```
    $return_url = empty(Yii::$app->request->get('return'))? \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/admin/default/index']) :Yii::$app->request->get('return');
    return $this->redirect($return_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the access section to set access to various actions in the controller.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['create', 'update','index'],
            'rules' => [
                // deny all POST requests
                [
                    'allow' => false,
                    'verbs' => ['POST']
                ],
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                // everything else is denied
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me.

```
use Yii;
use \yii\helpers\Url;

if ( Yii::$app->user->isGuest )
return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(array(Url::to(['site/login'])));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The Access Control Filter will do the work for you and redirects you to the configured user->loginUrl (config/main.php) if an action is not allowed.

Add the rule:

```
 array('deny',
    'users'=>array('?'),
),
```

To your base controller (f.e. ‘Controller’) where all your controllers are inherited from.

Answer (score 0):

I used index.php in my web/admin directory
This is the sample my index.php

```
 <?php
// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
    defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
    
    require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
    require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
    
    $config = require __DIR__ . '/../../config/web.php';
    $config["controllerNamespace"]='app\controllers\backend';
    (new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
    
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        $request_headers = apache_request_headers();
        $srv=$request_headers['Host'];
        header("Location: https://".$srv);
        die();
    }
```