# How to make user login works perfectly in yii2

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

Actually, I have worked in yii2 basic template where I have constructed different controllers, models, and views also developed a login system as well
but I want when to route to any action controller first it must make sure whether the user is login or not if the user is login then he or she must provide access otherwise should prompt the user to the login page.

I have communicated to some seniors but I am not able to convince my mind also make some research on different platforms like StackOverflow but still in halt.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227467/yii-2-redirecting-to-login-if-guest-visit-the-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227467/yii-2-redirecting-to-login-if-guest-visit-the-website)

Comment: Read This https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell on what you are looking for, a simple thing like this should do the trick:

```
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
```

You could also do it with the `behaviors` function using `AccessControl` like this:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::class,
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol). Is there something else you need? As far as I can tell, one of those should be able to help you, but let me know if there is something special you need.

Answer (score 0):

In the controlloer put behaviors function like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

The login function looks like this:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }

    $model->password = '';
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this at global level by using 'as beforeRequest' config in config/web.php file, below is the sample:

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
    ],
    'as beforeRequest' => [
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'rules' => [
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'actions' => ['login', 'forgot', 'verify', ],
            ],
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
        'denyCallback' => function () {
            return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
        },
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

If the user is not Logged-In then, the user will be redirected to site controller, login action.